# Do I have to use collection (and only collection) to build a form based on an entity (manytoone)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one

**CONTEXT:**
I want my **users** to be able to update or add their **marks** made regarding some **answer** (made by the community). This is made possible from the site on a web page where all answers (corresponding to a **question**) are displayed and for each answer, the marks of the user aside. (and only the one mark of the user)

**ENTITY STRUCTURE:**
Tag (n)<----->(n) Question (1)<---->(n) Answer (1)<--->(n) Marks (n)<---->(1) User

**TECHNICAL APPROCHE**
I retrieve from the Database all the Answers which are linked to a question and all the Marks linked to those answers. Then I modify my Answer Object to keep only the Marks from the current User. So (at this stage) **one answer has only one mark**.

**MY QUESTION**
I would like to know if I must use "collection" type to make my form because the two entities Answer and Marks are linked by a onetoMANY relationnship, while my current object (once the changed I made as explained before) as only one mark for each answer. I find it much more complexe to use collection and in this case it doesn't make any sense since I will only have one attribute Mark for any answer.

**MY CODE**

```
// PART OF CLASS answertype
// --------------------------
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('marks', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new MarkType(),
        ));
}

// PART OF CLASS marktype
// ----------------------
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('marks', 'choice', array(
            'type' => new MarkType(),
        ));
}
```

Comment: on a one to many, you can use "entity" for form field type

Comment: ok skrilled. but still why do I have to use collection or entity when I know that only one instance of Mark exist in my Object Answer?

Comment: entity should reflect that there is only one mark in the answer relationship unless you add multiple=true in form options, so this should be what you want? the default display would be a dropdown where you pick which one mark you want, but depending on how you choose to display form this can really be entered in whatever fashion you desire